# Given $|\arctan x| \leq \frac{\pi}{4}$ prove that $|\sin x| \leq 2\cos x $

Tags: trigonometry

Can anyone give me a hint about how to approach this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$|\arctan x| \leq \frac{\pi}{4}$ then $$\frac{\pi}{4}\le arctanx\le\frac{\pi}{4}$$ w have $$-\arctan2\le-1\le x\le1\le \arctan2$$ $\to$$$-2\le tanx\le2$$$$-2\le \frac{sinx}{cosx}\le2$$$$-2cosx\le sinx\le2cosx$$

Comment: How do you get to $$-\arctan2\le-1\le x\le1\le \arctan2$$?

Comment: @kkaploon:notice $tan(\frac{\pi}{4})\le tan(arctanx)\le tan(\frac{\pi}{4})$ $\arctan2=1.107148718\ge 1$ and $tan(arctanx)=x$

Comment: @ kkaploon:your welcome

Answer (score 2):

$|\arctan x| \leq \frac{\pi}{4}$ implies $-1\leq x \leq 1$.

Now if you convert $1$ radian into degrees, you will get around $57.3^0$ which is less than $60^0$ and so $tan 1 \leq tan (60^0)=\sqrt{3}\leq 2$ and in this interval cos(x) is positive.

Therefore $|tan(x)|\leq 2$  and from here your result follows

Comment: Why convert into degrees? Why not just say $1\leq \frac{\pi}{3}?$